# Feel I'm doing something wrong generating HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

```
public class BlogComment
{
    public int ID;
    public int UserID;
    public string Username;
    public string Comment;
    public DateTime Date;
    public int VotesUp;
    public int VotesDown;

    public Panel GetCommentPanel()
    {
        Panel WrapPanel = new Panel();
        WrapPanel.CssClass = "user-comment-wrapper";

        Panel VotePanel = new Panel();
        VotePanel.CssClass = "rfloat";
        HyperLink UpVote = new HyperLink();
        HyperLink DownVote = new HyperLink();
        UpVote.CssClass = "s vote-box vote-up";
        DownVote.CssClass = "s vote-box vote-down";
        UpVote.NavigateUrl="#";
        DownVote.NavigateUrl = "#";
        VotePanel.Controls.Add(UpVote);
        VotePanel.Controls.Add(DownVote);
        WrapPanel.Controls.Add(VotePanel);

        Panel UserTextPanel = new Panel();
        UserTextPanel.CssClass = "user-comment-txt";
        Literal UserText = new Literal();
        UserText.Text = this.Comment;
        UserTextPanel.Controls.Add(UserText);

        return WrapPanel;
    }
```

Trying to generate the following HTML:

```
<div class="user-comment-wrapper">
    <div style="float:right">
        <a class="s vote-box vote-up" href="#"></a>
        <a class="s vote-box vote-down" href="#"></a>
    </div>  
    <div class="user-comment-txt">
        Object comes with instantiated Department with empty atributes Object comes with instantiated Department with empty atributes Object comes with instantiated Department with empty atributes.Department with empty atributes Object comes with instantiated Department with empty atributes Object comes with instantiated Department with empty atributes.    
    </div>
    <div class="comment-info-wrapper">
        <div style="float:left">
            <strong>Posted by <a href="#">Tom</a></strong>
        </div>
        <div style="float:right">
            <strong><abbr class="timeago" title="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">July 17, 2008</abbr></strong>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>            
</div>
```

I mean it works, but I can't help but feel this design sucks.

Comment: Any reason you're generating the html along with style attributes (apart from writing your own blog engine - so many out there), as opposed to controlling the UI via CSS ?

Comment: @kd7, only because the only style attribute it needs is float:left or float:right which is the only exception I am designing to.

Comment: @Andy, I don't know, I was just thinking there would be an easier and more visual way to do this?  If I wanted to change the HTML of that blog comment box it's going to be a nightmare.

Comment: @Andy - because it violates separation of concerns by inserting display code in a model class.  A better way to do it would be to have a comment user control that uses the BlogComment class as data.  Better yet, switch to MVC and generate the HTML in a view.

Comment: @tvan, can I create a custom control, and then generate the control from the code behind? Would this work?

Comment: @Tom - if you substitute "populate" for "generate", I think so.  I think the HTML shouldn't be in code at all if you can avoid it.  Just populate placeholders if possible.

Comment: As others have said, you really don't want to generate HTML in this manner - it's damn near impossible to maintain, among other things. Also, replace you public fields with properties.

Comment: Have you looked in to the .NET mvc framework? Could make your job quite a bit easier.

Comment: It can be a tough thing coming from WebForms. I agree with tvanfosson but I wanted to understand what you thought - a little deeper than "it sucks" :) If you're able to, now is a great time to move to MVC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just write the plain old-good HTML in your ASPX page.

```
<div class="user-comment-wrapper">
    <div class="voting">
        <a class="s vote-box vote-up" href="#"></a>
        <a class="s vote-box vote-down" href="#"></a>
    </div>  
    <div class="user-comment-txt">
        <%: GetCommentContent() %>
    </div>
    <div class="comment-info-wrapper">
        <div class="author-info">
            <strong>Posted by 
              <a href="#"> <%: GetCommentAuthor() %></a>
            </strong>
        </div>
        <div class="comment-info">
            <strong>
              <abbr class="timeago" title="<%: GetShortCommentTime() %>">
                <%: GetFriendlyCommentTime() %>
              </abbr>
            </strong>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>            
</div>
```

Please not the additional classes applied. Then you can add CSS:

```
.user-comment-wrapper .voting { float: right; }
.comment-info-wrapper .author-info { float: left; }
.comment-info-wrapper .comment-info { float: right; }
```

Also you are injecting content using ASP.NET 4 `<%:..%>` (or it can be a usual `<%=...%>`, but make sure you HTML escape it).

I don't see any reason to manually create those absolutely unreadable server-side controls in order to render HTML.

Comment: Thanks, can this go in a repeater?  I've never used repeaters before

Comment: Yes, it can. You will only need to change the way you inject content into the HTML. But again, I do not see a reason to use Repeater :)